# Disable alt tab and taskbars

Tags: shortcut-keys, taskbar

I'm creating kiosks for public use and I'm trying to make them as tamper proof as possible. Many have keyboards attached so I'm trying to disable alt-tab to stop them switching out of my locked down environment, how can I do this?

Also, is there a way I can disable the unity bars up the left and top? Or the gnome bars across the top and bottom? They make it very easy for the user to break out of the locked down environment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not sound like you want to use a full-blown Ubuntu with the Unity desktop environment for this. Generally speaking, there are many window managers that allow more precise control of input.

In case you are new to Linux and graphical environments: There are three aspects of how linux renders nice, high-resolution output - the X-Server, responsible for hardware interaction, the window manager (metacity in the case of unity), which offers ... well, the ability to manage windows (i.e. close programs, move windows, etc.) and, finally (and optionally) the Desktop Environment. This is what adds all the fancy buttons, taskbars, the clock, etc.

If you only want one window to run, you should probably look into more cut-down graphical solutions, especially because your use-case does not require a full-blown Desktop Environment in the first place.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30207/debian-based-system-only-one-gui-program-nothing-else) StackExchange article offers some further recommendations. You could, e.g. look into the program [Sabayon](http://live.gnome.org/Sabayon/), or, which may be more fitting, use the linux distribution Fedora, which [offers](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/kiosk/) a specific kiosk variant.